# php SPlSubject requires method update

Tags: php, interface

update() MUST be used in a class that implements SplSubject. BUT update() isn't in that interface..

But update is not declared in SplSubject Interface !

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

`update()` is a method in SplObserver interface, and should be defined in the class that implements SplObserver.